# how to edit echo $OUTPUT->main_content() MOODLE

Tags: php, moodle

How to change the contents of this output??

I'm trying to change , but can not find the file q make this change

how to edit echo $OUTPUT->main_content();

in BCU theme

Answer (score 4):

The `function main_content()` is in `/lib/outputrenderers.php`

But you should override it by adding `function main_content()` to `class theme_bcu_core_renderer` in `/theme/bcu/renderers.php`

Comment: if you managed to understand what that question says, could you please edit it so that it makes some sense...

Comment: ok, thanks!, but, i need change this... -> <li id="section-2" class="section main clearfix" role="region" aria-label="coruse 1"><span class="hidden sectionname"> and this is not in main_content()