# Moodle remove content in front page of custome theme

Tags: php, moodle

I am trying to develop a custom theme for moodle. I have followed the instructions in the tutorial https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Creating_a_theme to customize the front page. In the front page I don't want to show the contents from moodle. So I tried removing `core_renderer::MAIN_CONTENT_TOKEN` , then it is showing the error

```
Coding error detected, it must be fixed by a programmer: page layout file [dirroot]/theme/mentornetz/layout/frontpage.php does not contain the main content placeholder, please include "<?php echo $OUTPUT->main_content() ?>" in theme layout file?
```

How can I remove the content without showing the error.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you cannot avoid to call the `main_content()` function.

The main_content() function prints a string like this:

```
<div role="main">[MAIN CONTENT GOES HERE - W6ATMmqMgo]</div>
```

where Moodle injects its (main area) content.

The fact is, if you want to create a new theme, there must be some place where Moodle injects its dynamic content. Otherwise, there is no need of having Moodle at all:-)

What you can do, however is:

- Define some custom content above and (or below) this line (i.e. above or below the content area). Or
- Simply define a static page, not related to Moodle content at all.

You also could override the `main_content()` function, if you want. Please refer to the first answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35607210/how-to-edit-echo-output-main-content-moodle) question for details.

Comment: also known as the only answer. too bad the top related answers to this question are effectively "who knows"